# Django Tastypie prevent file uri's being saved to a FileField

Tags: django-models, tastypie

I've got a Django app with Tastypie, and mainly BackBone client side. One of my models has a few ImageFields. Here is a similar setup to help me explain the issue.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

**models.py**

```
class Foo(models.model):
    bar = models.ImageField()
    baz = models.CharField()
```

**api.py**

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset=models.Foo.objects.all()
        resource_name = "foo"
        authorization = Authorization()
```

When I make a GET request to the API, it appends the MEDIA_URL to the file names to return the URI where a bar can be accessed. However, when I change the value of baz on a row, and then make a PUT request with that, it also changes the value for a bar to the URI. This means that the next time I GET the row, it appends the MEDIA_URL again, breaking the system and appending it for each successive GET and PUT. I end up with values for bar in the DB that look like.

```
/media/media/media/bar.jpg
```

I think I should fix this by overriding a method in my ModelResource, so that when there is a PUT request, it recognizes that it's getting either a URI or a real file, and alters its behavior in some way.

Is this the correct fix? Could you provide some implementation details of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Tastypie is well designed, similarly to Django. Unfortunately I was not familiar with the terminology so when I read the docs I didn't understand. You can easily modify behavior of the API at many levels. Here is my new API definition, which fixed the issue.

**api.py**

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset=models.Foo.objects.all()
        resource_name = "foo"
        authorization = Authorization()

    def hydrate_bar(bundle):
        bundle["bar"] = bundle["bar"].strip(MEDIA_URL)
        return bundle
```

I should add that this only works for me because I exclusively POST my image files individually with a post_detail method which doesn't call this method. If I was to POST or PUT image files as part of the entire row, I expect this might raise an error if that isn't considered.